# Java : Class cast Exception with java and externam API

Tags: java, exception, hadoop

I am writing a jave based hadoop map reduce code -- . I am invoking a external library to process my data. I am getting the class cast exception.
Please tell me me the reason and possible solution.

```
public void map(Object key, DocR value, Context context) {

    DataToHdfs test = null;
    try {
        docs = new DocR(new File(AnnotationExtration.INPUT_LOCATION));


     compiledAql=AnnotationExtration.aog;

    SystemX.Single syst = new SystemX.Single(compiledAql, AnnotationExtration.docSchema);
    String combinedResult="";
    while (docs.hasNext()) {
```

........ doing some processing and sending the data HDFS.

```
if((combinedResult)!=null){

                            test.writToHdfs(combinedResult);
                        }
                System.out.println(combinedResult);


                // Writing to HDFS.
 context.write(new Text("1",),new Text(combinedResult));
```

the exception  is  :--

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to com.somepackage.api.DocR
at   com.somePackage.AnnotationExtrationMapper.map(AnnotationExtrationMapper.java:1)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:212)
12/08/28 13:02:23 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
12/08/28 13:02:23 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_local_0001
```

Thanks

Comment: at what line in your code is exception been thrown?

Comment: at com.somepackage.AnnotationExtrationMapper.map(AnnotationExtrationMapper.java:1)
 package com.somepackage; At the begining of the code.

Comment: I mean in your custom class, what line and what code have you written there

Comment: @RohitHaritash I think he meant: what code is at line 1 in AnnotationExtrationMapper.java?

Comment: @  public void map(Object key, DocReader value, Context context) {

Comment: @RohitHaritash Just out of curiosity, how can you have a method declaration on the first line of a java source file? Doesn't all methods need to be contained within a class, which need to be declared before the method declaration? :S

Comment: sorry my mistake !! By first line means Method I was not considering the class and package declaration

Answer (score 0):

That exception typically means that you are trying to cast something incorrectly.
If you do:

```
Text foo = new Text("bar");
map(someKey, (DocR) foo, someContext);
```

Then you will get a ClassCastException because of the `(DocR) foo`, since the `Text` instance is in no way a `DocR` object.

I think you got the line on which the exception occurs wrong. A method declaration typically cannot cause a class cast exception.

Search in AnnotationExtrationMapper.java for `(DocR)`. That cast operator is likely to be present at whatever place the problem is.